What is the problem in the follwing code for plotting Poincaré Sections with DDE
I want to plot the Poincaré Sections for the given DDE. Kindly suggest what mistake I made in the following code?
data = Block[{G = 3.55, \[Tau] = 3.33}, 
    Reap[NDSolve[{v'[t] == 2*G*BesselJ[1, v[t - \[Tau]]] - v[t], 
       v[0] == 0.01, 
       WhenEvent[Mod[t, 2 \[Pi]] == 0, Sow[v[t]]]}, {}, {t, 0, 
       100000}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]]]][[-1, 1]];
ListPlot[data, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, All}, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.0025]]


What is the empty curly bracket {} for?

Your plot is empy because you said PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, All}, change that to Automatic then it show the points.

@mattiav27 that empty {} is because code seems to be using the example in this help page https://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/PoincareSections.html  which has empty {} there.

Thank you very much, how to get chaotic  attractor
